# Parse default Emails with MailGun API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, mailgun

I have developped an iOS and Android App with Parse Backend. I have setup mailgun API and cloud code too. But i want help for "How to send all parse default emails to users using mailgun API. Emails like (Verify Email, Reset password, etc..).How can i send welcome email to user after signup?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Mailgun instead of using default Prase mailing system, you need to implement those features like mail verification, password rest, ..etc yourself.

Comment: That because i'm asking how to do it. Can you help me please??